# Redirect colored output to file

Tags: macos, colors, zsh, redirection

I want to store a colored terminal output to a file (maybe a .rtf or whatever).
In OSX I am able to manually copy it and paste it in a .rft file using Textedit, however I wanted to store it automatically using something like:

```
command &> somefile.rtf
```

Storing the output in a .txt preserves the color tags but they are useless since they can only be seen from the terminal (using cat).

Is there a way to do that?

I read a [similiar question](https://superuser.com/questions/493870/store-grep-output-with-formatting-as-it-is-to-a-file/493872#493872) but it didn't solve the issue of storing the output in a file format that supports colors (and can be opened without a terminal).

Comment: In what way(s) did the other question/answers not "solve it" for you?  What happened when you tried those suggestion solutions?

Comment: have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245121/a-library-to-convert-ansi-escapes-terminal-formatting-color-codes-to-html - in the comments on `aha` c program it says '(...) compiles and runs without problem on os x'

Comment: It is just solving the issue of not removing the color tags using grep. I need to store the colored output in a file that can be opened without using a terminal (a .doc, .rtf, .ods, etc.) [I edited my question]

Comment: In case you still need it, you can pass through the html format (then you can convert to whatever else). There is a [script v0.23](http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/ansi2html.sh) or the older [v 0.15](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pixelb/scripts/bd2aabd/scripts/ansi2html.sh), that you can use so `command | ansi2html.sh > file.html`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the colours are stored with their ansi sequence you can create a script to *translate*  each of them... or you can use a script just made.

For example it exists the script ansi2html <sup>[[v0.15](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pixelb/scripts/bd2aabd/scripts/ansi2html.sh),[v0.23](http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/ansi2html.sh)]</sup> that you can make executable, put in a directory of your path (typically `~/bin`)
and use with

```
command | ansi2html.sh > file.html
```

Then if you need a different format you can convert it or you can rewrite the script.

Note that some commands know if their output is piped or not.
For example, `ls`  may change its output if piped.